# Add automatic nodes? Blender does not recognize materials in this format

Tags: python, rendering, texturing, materials, node-editor

When I import a .smd file to blender (yes, it's a addon), the textures are not rendered, it's like the material is not applied and I need to add 1 node for each texture and it's too much work.. is there another way?

[image]

with other formats, for example .obj, it is not necessary to add nodes, blender perfectly recognizes the textures

Comment: I made a script for this exact purpose. Here it is on GitHub, along with one for fixing the armatures. https://github.com/thelabcat/SMD-Model-PostImport

Comment: How exactly does it work? I have added the script, added the folder path and run it, but I don't see the changes :(

https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/472521435676672010/939964215190487101/Captura.JPG?width=775&height=566

Comment: Did you follow the instructions written out in the script?

Comment: Yes, I added my directory to the MAT_PATH, as in the example. I do not understand the function of NAME_SIZE, my files do not have any character of type '_'

Comment: Yeah, not all Source games work quite the same way. Most of the files I was working with were from sonic generations. You can get some of those models from models-resource.com if you want to see what kind of file names I was working with. Name size is a component of the function that is meant to identify whether an image is related to a material or not. Modify that function as necessary.